# Magento 1.9.4.0 CMS Block Widget Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block, widget, widgets, widget-instance

I'm trying to add widget to cms block or page but when i add it only display short code on page and not render, i tried different magento default widgets results is same

[image]

also tried using code on phtml template

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-top-cms')->toHtml()
```

But it also gives same results.

also checked by adding block type to system permission but still no luck, anyone know how fix this issue please

Comment: It could be theme related. Have you checked with magento's default theme?

Comment: So after investigating, it looks like the new magento is throwing out your old layout, and using it's own. you was able to copy/paste the block code into the 2columns-right.phtml and it is working as it should now. 

link :- **https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/Static-blocks-not-appearing-on-1-9-2/td-p/33220**